# Toggle showing only clicked content - hiding other

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

i need help with toggle content - in few columns i made hidden content which is showing on button click. (click on btn-show toggle content in pane bio-text)

```
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
 <div class="bio"><a class="btn-show">Arnold Schwarzenegger,Chairman, CEO    &amp; Partner</a></div>
 <p class="bio-text" style="display: none;">Arnold Alois Schwarzenegger (born July 30, 1947) is an Austrian-American actor, model, producer, director, activist, businessman, investor, writer, philanthropist, former professional bodybuilder, and politician. Schwarzenegger served two terms as the 38th Governor of California from 2003 until 2011.</p>
</div>
```

Now i have 4 wrappers like this.
It is implemented via jQuery. Problem is, how is currently made, it support all toggles to be active. I need to reformat my code to allow only 1 to be active (click on other hide all expanded content except clicked one)
Here is a code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.bio-text').hide();
    $('.btn-show').click(function () {
        // $this determines which button clicked on
        var $this = $(this);
        // grab the text that is NEXT to the button that was clicked on
        //var theText = $this.next();
        var theText = $this.parent().next(".bio-text");
        // Change the text of the button depending on if the text is hidden
        theText.slideToggle(500);
        $this.parent().toggleClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

So this is working, but allows all panes to be opened at same time. 
I need help to make this exclusive- only 1 content pane showed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the full markup so we can help.

Comment: are you trying to make accordian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just hide everything within the click function first, then slide the correct one open.

PS: Sorry, I shortened the javascript code a bit.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.bio-text').hide();
  $('.btn-show').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.bio-text:visible').slideUp(500).parent().removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).next(':hidden').slideDown(500).parent().addClass('highlight');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
<a class="btn-show">Arnold Schwarzenegger,Chairman, CEO &amp; Partner</a>
<p class="bio-text">Arnold Alois Schwarzenegger (born July 30, 1947) is an Austrian-American actor, model, producer, director, activist, businessman, investor, writer, philanthropist, former professional bodybuilder, and politician. Schwarzenegger served two terms as the 38th Governor of California from 2003 until 2011.</p>
</div>
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
<a class="btn-show">Someone else</a>
<p class="bio-text">Texts</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think that's the `HTML` the user has. You can see clearly from the code that he looks for a `parent` element.

Comment: This is not working properly too.. What if i want to have initial state like on start-all panels hidden? Hre is the thing - click on first-expand first...Imagine next step- i haven't collapsed previous panel and clicked on button 2 for panel 2. I need functionality to show then just panel 2 all other closed . Now more clear?

Comment: @Lanchushki, no, you need to post the full code. That's why people are confused. Please post the whole HTML.

Comment: I understood you want an accordion, which is like my example.
Click 'Run code snippet' to see it in action.
All bio-text are initially hidden. Click on the first will open the first. Click on the second will close the first and open the second.
I had to guess your html for this.

Comment: @JaapBroeders Yes, but i want possibility to collapse expanded section when click on button link for expanded one... So from your code i can not make initial state-all panels closed.
See this [link](http://www.insigniacap.com/team/)

Answer (score 0):

You can write the script like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.bio-text').hide();
    $('.btn-show').click(function () {
    $('.bio-text').hide();
        $(this).next('p').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

ex: https://jsfiddle.net/nkgLzaeq/

If you want to keep active for only 1 panel, you need to remove active class and hide all of panel, after that set active for current panel

Comment: I don't think that's the `HTML` the user has. You can see clearly from the code that he looks for a `parent` element.

Comment: He don't show a fully markup of HTML so i think he only want to know how to write the script for active only 1 panel.

Comment: @NguyễnHuy exactly